# SSRS must Excel be installed on Reporting server to use Excel as a Data SOURCE?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, datasource, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

If users would like to use Excel as a data source for Report Builder (of SSRS - SQL Server Reporting Services), does Excel need to be installed on the Report Server?  We also have issues with 32-bit ODBC drivers vs 64 bit drivers but I want to rule out (or rule in) that Excel needs to be on the Server.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to install Excel.

The MS Business Intelligence Development Studio (ie. Visual Studio) is 32-bit and you need 32-bit ODBC drivers for report development. I'll assume your Report Server is 64-bit, so you'll need 64-bit drivers for that. You can download both of the drivers here: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Took me a long time to figure out how to cope with 32-bit editor and 64-bit server, but here's the deal:

1. Install the 64-bit drivers **first**
2. Go to Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)
3. Add a new data source (you can mention in the description that this is the 64-bit data source)
4. Install the 32-bit drivers **second**
5. Run C:\Windows\SysWoW64\Odbcad32.exe as administrator
6. Add a new data source (you can mention in the description that this is the 32-bit data source)
7. Create a data source (eg. "MyDataSource") in Report Server (only available option should be the 64-bit version)
8. Create a data source in Report Builder or BIDS (only available option should be the 32-bit version) with the same name that you used in the last step ("MyDataSource")

Now when you deploy the report, the data source created in Report Builder or BIDS doesn't override the data source on the Report Server and you can use the 32-bit data source in the editor and 64-bit data source on the Report Server.